# Ignore TS6133: "(import) is declared but never used"?

Tags: typescript

While working on a TypeScript project, I commented out a line, and got the error:

> Failed to compile
>
> ```
> ./src/App.tsx
> (4,8): error TS6133: 'axios' is declared but never used.
> ```
>
> This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

The error is right, I am importing axios, but I wanted to temporarily comment out the call to `axios.get`. I appreciate that error as it keeps my imports clean, but during early development is is pretty disruptive.

Any way to disable or ignore that warning?

Answer (score 99):

You probably have the `noUnusedLocals` compiler option turned on in your `tsconfig.json`. Just turn it off during development.

Comment: In my case I also forgot to restart `npm run start` for changes to take effect.

Comment: It won't if you disable `noUnusedLocals` in the `tsconfig.json` file you are using for buildiing.

Comment: can this be set as a warning?

Comment: @GuillermoRuffino - I sort of agree -- making this a warning would be create mildly annoying warnings in modern editors, but making it a compiler error ensures that you only ever build 'clean code'.

Comment: If anyone else is still getting the errors after changing the option make sure there aren't any other tsconfig files in your project. If you're using vscode open the command palette (ctrl + p) and start typing tsconfig to find other files. I had a tsconfig.app.json that was overriding the one at the root

Comment: this warning it only serves to remember not to use variables without being used, but this can be false positive, because sometimes we use the variables inside '' and even then the error is returned.

Comment: So changing the noUsedLocals field (tsconfig file) from true to false seems like a really good idea.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. By default `noUsedLocals` is false according to docs. However, omitting it still shows the error, and the error persists even with it being set to false. After  TS server & vscode restart.

There are no other tsconfig files either.

Answer (score 18):

**In tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "noUnusedLocals": false,   // just set this attribute false
  }
}
```

It will be done.

**For more tips:**

In xxx.ts file

```js
//@ts-nocheck 
when on the top of the file,it will not check the below.

//@ts-ignore
when use it,it will not check the next line
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in my React App. Apart from changing the  `"noUsedLocals": false` property in the `tsconfig.json`, you also need to adjust the `"noUnusedParameters": false`. The former is only applicable to local variables, if you are passing unused parameters through functions, the latter will need to be changed to false as well.

In summary, you'll have to do the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "noUnusedLocals": false,
     "noUnusedParameters": false,
 }
}
```

Comment: I just set both of these values to `false` like in your example and restarted the TS server, and made sure I have only one tsconfig.json file. Doesn't work. Although in my case it's neither a local or parameter, it's a function.