# Iterating with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do you iterate N times when during each iteration you only want to use the key (index) of the iteration? There’s no array to iterate through - you could create an array like `[...Array(num)]` and call `map()` or `forEach()` on it, but then how can you use the key in each iteration without using the item (which in this case would be undefined) and without the TypeScript compiler moaning about it:

> item is declared but its value is never read

Is this a use case for the old for loop or can it be done in a simpler/safer way?

```
{[...Array(totalNum)].map((item: any, key: number) => {
    // if I console.log(item), tsc won't moan, but clearly not a solution
    return (
        <SomeComponent key={key}>
        </SomeComponent>
    )
})}
```

Comment: What are you looking for in a "simpler/safer way"? Right now, it reads very opinonated and may be closed due to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a `_` in front of the parameter to indicate that the non-use of the parameter is deliberate can solve the warning:

```
[...Array(totalNum)].map((_item, key) => {
```

(note that explicitly declaring the types of the parameters is not required; it just adds extra syntax noise here)

If you want to remove the unused parameter completely, you can iterate over the keys of the array with `Object.keys`:

```
Object.keys([...Array(totalNum)]).map((key) => {
```

Comment: It's worth noting that it's not typescript but tslint that is complaining about unused variable.  Prefixing variable with `_` will only work if the rule is configured like `"no-unused-variable": [true, {"ignore-pattern": "^_"}]`

Comment: It's not just a TSLint error, it's a TS error too. Eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565671/ignore-ts6133-import-is-declared-but-never-used

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do this a lot in my codebase, and I made a handy helper called `mapTimes()`

```
/** Returns an array of the return value of `fn` run `times` number of times. */
export function mapTimes<T>(times: number, fn: (index: number) => T): T[] {
  const arr: T[] = []

  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    arr.push(fn(i))
  }

  return arr
}
```

I basically just build an array with value of the same integer as its index. Then you pass a function to map over it.

Usage:

```
{mapTimes(totalNum, (key: number) => {
    return (
        <SomeComponent key={key}>
        </SomeComponent>
    )
})}
```