# Getting error when running a test : TS6196 is declared but never used

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, eslint, typescript-eslint

Trying to write a simple test following this guide https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-setting-up-unit-tests-with-typescript-871c0f4f1609 but I get `TS6196: 'HelloWorldServiceUnitTests' is declared but never used.` error when I run the test.

./register.js

```
const tsNode = require('ts-node');
const testTSConfig = require('./test/tsconfig.json');

tsNode.register({
  files: true,
  transpileOnly: true,
  project: './test/tsconfig.json'
});
```

./mocharc.json

```
{
  "require": "./register.js",
  "reporter": "dot"
}
```

./nycrc.json

```
{
  "extends": "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript",
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/"
  ],
  "extension": [
    ".ts"
  ],
  "reporter": [
    "text-summary",
    "html"
  ],
  "report-dir": "./coverage"
}
```

./test/hello-world-service.unit.test.ts

```
import {suite, test} from '@testdeck/mocha';
import * as _chai from 'chai';

_chai.should();

@suite
class HelloWorldServiceUnitTests {
    // eslint-disable-next-line require-jsdoc
    @test 'should do something when call a method'() {
        const list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        console.log(list);
    }
}
```

[image]

#### Setting `noUnusedLocals: false` in `./test/tsconfig.json` still throws an error when running the test:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
test/hello-world-service.unit.test.ts(7,7): error TS6196: 'HelloWorldServiceUnitTests' is declared but never used.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your `noUnusedLocals` option off in your `tsconfig.json`

Same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565671/ignore-ts6133-import-is-declared-but-never-used)

Comment: Is it possible to configure `noUnusedLocals` rule so it only applies to Classes which have `@suite` decorator?

Comment: you can configure the `compileroptions` with `include` and `exclude` by selecting the file, but cant include by anotations

`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
  },
  "include": ["*"],
  "exclude": ["myFolder/myFile"]
}
`

Comment: Setting `noUnusedLocals: false` in `./test/tsconfig.json` turns off the IDE warning but the test still fails when I run it. See updated question.

Comment: From the tutorial, did you copy the `tsconfig.json` config ? and your `HelloWorldServiceUnitTests` is not the same. Try copying the same content than the tutorial.

Comment: Yes. Is there anyway to configure that `./test/tsconfig.json` when running the test? Looks to me that it's how the test is launched.

Comment: The tests files location is defined in the `package.json`. The `tsconfig.json` is used to specifies the root files and the compiler options required to compile the project